# Copy question / comment text including formatting

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions

NOTE: I realise that there is other questions already out there that ask about copying data from other websites into this one. This is not what my "question" is about.

Occasionally I have had need to copy and paste a comment that I made into another question/answer. The comments invariably have italics and/or bolded text in them, likewide some have non-naked links.

However (in FF, if this matters) when I copy and paste these, I only get the text, no formatting, or href's.

On various Google services (Most prominent, I think) Calendar, when clicking to start a drag and copy operation on a pre-existing appointment, in a pop-up, it puts the text into a textbox to allow you to copy (and also edit, which is not part of what I am suggesting here).

Can functionality be developed to allow users to click into a question / comment, have it switched out for it's markdown equivalent while focus in on that box, to allow copying and pasting of all that is required to make a duplicate?

Comment: You should never have to post duplicate question or answer content. You obviously shouldnt be posting duplicate questions and if you are having to post the same answer multiple times then the question is most likely a duplicate. Regarding the comment there is a userscript that has been created for "canned" comments on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Josh Mein - I must not have explained myself well enough. This is not a canned response. I have _occasionally_ "needed" to because one solution can sometimes work to solve many problems. The way to `set`, then `echo`, variables in a `cmd` `for` loop is a situation that I have seen questions about, but different specifics. If the questions were to be closed as duplicates (What I believe you are suggesting as a solution), the uniqueness of each situation would not be addressed.

Comment: Your example does seems like a perfect example of what should be marked as duplicate. The specifics will rarely be the same as people are always working on something different, but their is a basic solution that will solve their problem. It all boils down to the user not understanding a basic of the php language.

Comment: Guess we will have to agree to disagree. I have seen many questions where the issue boils down to a user not understanding that there is even standard or delayed expansion, let alone the pro/cons of each. These questions appear to all mostly still be open. Think it is far easier for those who don't understand how something works to see an example that is similar to their own, and not instead just a one-size-fits-all Q&A.